# How can I simulate the value of a variable using 'when' with mockito?

Tags: android, mockito

I'm making a simple test using *`when`* in mockito.

I've read that *`when`* only works for functions for returning values, so I want to make something like this from a variable:

```
when(config.orientation).thenReturn(1);
```

What other way can I take to set that `orientation` value?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read correctly, when only works for functions returning values.  It does it by replacing these functions with mocks.  You can't do it with the object attributes,  since nothing is being called,  so there is nothing to intercept.

If config.orientation is a public attribute you can just set it before running the tests.  If it's private you can use something like [Fest-Reflect](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-reflect)